# Progressbar color in PrimeFaces

Tags: css, primefaces, xhtml, progress-bar, background-color

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0 and I want to change the progressBar color.

HTML :

```
<p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{myBean.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" global="false" styleClass="myPb"/>
```

CSS :

```
.myPb .ui-progressbar-value {
    background-image:  #f47920;
}
```

This doesn't work ! What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this solution from the PrimeFaces forum?

```
.ui-progressbar.ui-widget-content {
    background-color:#f47920;
    background-image:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".ui-progressbar-value").css("background","green");
</script>
```

Comment: The selector you use here is less specific than in the Q. Sure this one works?